# Optimization in Memcpy implementation

Tags: c, optimization

Below is the code which I got while searching for an optimized `memcpy` implementation.
Here's the [**link**](https://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4024961/Optimizing-Memcpy-improves-speed)

```
void *memcpy(void *dst, void const *src, size_t len) {
    long *plDst = (long *)dst;
    long const *plSrc = (long const *)src;

    if (!(src & 0xFFFFFFFC) && !(dst & 0xFFFFFFFC)) {
        while (len >= 4) {
            *plDst++ = *plSrc++;
            len -= 4;
        }
    }

    char *pcDst = (char *)plDst;
    char const *pcDst = (char const *)plSrc;

    while (len--) {
         *pcDst++ = *pcSrc++;
    }

    return (dst);
}
```

Can somebody explain the line below to me?

```
if (!(src & 0xFFFFFFFC) && !(dst & 0xFFFFFFFC))
```

Here they want to check if `src` and `dst` address are aligned to a `4 byte` boundary or not. Why are they using `!` though, as it will make the condition `false` every time?

Secondly, is there any scope for more optimization in the above code?

Comment: Why do you think the condition might be false everytime?

Comment: Looks like a typo in the article - it should probably be: `if (!(src & ~0xFFFFFFFC) && !(dst & ~0xFFFFFFFC))`.

Comment: For checking alignment you might want to use `!(src&3) && !(dst&3)` The condition in the snippet check something different

Comment: Also the first comment of this article notices this typo

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Alignment is now clear.
Can we do some more optimization in the code to make it faster ?
What if we didn't check for 4 byte alignment ?

Comment: If your CPU does not allow 32bit read access to unaligned addresses you could get SEGFAULT or wrong content. Or you could suffer from a huge penalty in speed of memory accesses....

Comment: To be really optimised for larger transfers it should check if  the start is aligned - copy byte by byte the unaligned one, the copy the native length ones

Comment: @Abhi you can extent the code with the use of more special-cases (e.g for 64 Bit), but you should be carefull here, since the compiler can optimize the code too.

Comment: Ok.Address should be aligned but is it require that both src and dest should be aligned. Otherwise we can use the method told by @ P__J__

Answer (score 4):

This article, while addressing an interesting subject, falls short of providing correct examples. The code posted is referred to as *GNU's newlib source code*. Both the GNU project and the newlib team will be surprised to learn of this unexpected convergence statement! the *newlib* is not a GNU project and most of its source code is not GPL licenced.

This *optimized* implementation of `memcpy` is non portable, sub-optimal and in many aspects incorrect.

The test `if (!(src & 0xFFFFFFFC) && !(dst & 0xFFFFFFFC))` attempts to detect if the `src` and `dst` addresses are aligned on `long` boundaries. It is cumbersome and non portable for multiple reasons and downright incorrect as you noticed:

- implicit conversion from `void *` to `int` is ugly and implementation defined. The pointers should be cast as `(uintptr_t)` for better portability.
- `0xFFFFFFFC` assumes type `long` is 4 bytes. This may be incorrect, and indeed type `long` is 8-byte long on 64-bit linux and Mac systems.
- `src & 0xFFFFFFFC` is not a check for alignment and is unlikely to be `0`, the intended test for alignment on 4-byte boundaries is `src & 3`.

Furthermore, the code fails to optimize the case where `src` and `dst` have the same alignment but are not aligned on `long` boundaries.

Other possible improvements include unrolling the loops, using a switch for small values of `len`, combining bytes read from `src` into `long`s to write to `dst` once its is aligned on `long` boundaries...

Here is an improved alternative:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void *memcpy(void *dst, void const *src, size_t len) {
    unsigned char *pcDst = (unsigned char *)dst;
    unsigned char const *pcSrc = (unsigned char const *)src;

    if (len >= sizeof(long) * 2
    &&  ((uintptr_t)src & (sizeof(long) - 1)) == ((uintptr_t)dst & (sizeof(long) - 1))) {
        while (((uintptr_t)pcSrc & (sizeof(long) - 1)) != 0) {
            *pcDst++ = *pcSrc++;
            len--;
        }
        long *plDst = (long *)pcDst;
        long const *plSrc = (long const *)pcSrc;
        /* manually unroll the loop */
        while (len >= sizeof(long) * 4) {
            plDst[0] = plSrc[0];
            plDst[1] = plSrc[1];
            plDst[2] = plSrc[2];
            plDst[3] = plSrc[3];
            plSrc += 4;
            plDst += 4;
            len -= sizeof(long) * 4;
        }
        while (len >= sizeof(long)) {
            *plDst++ = *plSrc++;
            len -= sizeof(long);
        }
        pcDst = (unsigned char *)plDst;
        pcSrc = (unsigned char const *)plSrc;
    }
    while (len--) {
         *pcDst++ = *pcSrc++;
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Note that the casts from `void *` are unnecessary in C, but required in C++.

Here are some important points to keep in mind when trying to optimize code for speed:

- no trade-offs on correctness. Fast code that fails even on border cases is useless.
- beware of portability issues: solutions that depend on type sizes and/or byte order may create portability problems.
- benchmarking will tell what works and what does not: you must carefully time the various alternatives on a variety of test cases.
- there is no perfect solution: faster code on one architecture can be slower on a different one including and most problematically on a future one. Benchmark on different architectures.
- fight complexity: avoid convoluted solutions that do not bring substantial improvements, their correctness is more difficult to prove and to maintain.
- `memcpy` is usually optimized in assembly or implemented as a built-in by modern compilers.

Comment: I'd suggest checking for `len <= 8` before doing anything else, and using a `switch` statement to handle short copy operations.  That would avoid the need to check whether you can copy data up to the point where the source and/or destination come into alignment.  I'd suggest copying data until the destination is aligned, and then if source isn't in alignment and the copy is "big", having the main loop be something like `x = *adjustedSrc++; *dest++ = (x << shift1) | (y >> shift2); y=x;`, thus avoiding any need to decompose operations into smaller chunks.

Comment: @supercat: good points. regarding the combination of unaligned source bytes into `long`s for storing into an aligned destination address, it is easy to overlook the byte order issue. Depending on the architecture, it might not even be faster. As a matter of fact, on x86 targets where unaligned reads and writes are allowed,  a simple read/write loop via a 64-bit type may be the fastest solution. Benchmarking is the judge.

Comment: Not to mention that optimizing `memcpy()` is very processor-specific. On x86, often the memcpy-opcode is best, or at least reasonable enough.